# Initiate class from dynamically loaded framework in swift

Tags: swift, dynamic, frameworks, dlopen

Here is some context around my question.

My custom developed framework ("Custom.framework") has to dynamically load 3rd party frameworks ("Dynamic1.framework" and "Dynamic2.framework") using dlopen. Reason I need this is that I should support several implementations of some 'functionality', which these framework provide, based on what frameworks are used in the client apps (that use my custom framework).

Also some parts of my framework are written in ObjC and other using Swift.
Dynamic1.framework is being called from Objc and Dynamic2.framework is being called from Swift. 
Using Dynamic1 from ObjC I have no issues: I've made protocol wrappers for classes I use from it, load framework using dlopen, then instantiate. Below code I wrote:

```
#import "dlfcn.h"

@protocol Dynamic1ClassProtocol
+ (nullable instancetype)shared;
- (void)doSmth;
@end

void *frameworkHandle = dlopen("Dynamic1.framework/Dynamic", RTLD_LAZY);
Class x = NSClassFromString(@"Dynamic1Class");
if (x)
{
      NSObject <Dynamic1ClassProtocol> *instance = [x shared];
      [instance doSmth];
}
```

But I have troubles using classes loaded in swift. I also created protocols wrappers with methods to imitate actual classes from Dynamic2.framework. I can load the framework and get 'Type' object from the framework. But I cant find a way how to really instantiate an object. 
Here is the code:

```
@objc public protocol Dynamic2ClassProtocol: NSObjectProtocol {
    init()
}

let handle = dlopen("Dynamic2.framework/Dynamic2", RTLD_LAZY)
let x = NSClassFromString("Dynamic2Class")
if let type = x {
    let casted = type as! Dynamic2ClassProtocol.Type
    let instance = casted.init()
}
```

It compiles but in run time it crashes:

```
Could not cast value of type 'Dynamic2Class' (0x100f28670) to 'AppName.Dynamic2ClassProtocol' (0x100a832d0).
```

If do not use force casting but conditional one, it always returns nil.
So I do not know other ways how to do it.

Also I didn't see anywhere that loading dynamically framework in swift doestn't work at all, so probably I'm doing smth wrong. Please help

Answer (score 3):

Swift class names should include the module name.

```
let aClass = NSClassFromString("DynamicFramework.DynamicClassExample")
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `Dynamic2Class` an NSObject subclass? (Because that's a requirement for NSClassFromString to work properly I guess.

You could use `Bundle` to load frameworks at runtime. See an example here:

https://github.com/pendowski/SwiftPluginsExample

No sure how well `dlopen` really works with Swift. I wonder if any of that works on Linux

You can also have a look at

https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/tree/master/CoreFoundation/PlugIn.subproj

Where this is implemented for the open source Swift foundation

Comment: Thanks, for reply. Yes, Dynamic2Class is NSObject subclass. 
dlopen works in swift, I can call C functions using dlsym. Using Bundles is not case for me, but maybe it would help someone. Also I've tried to declare Dynamic2ClassProtocol in ObjC as advised in article from your first link but it didn't work for me as well, as swift continues not to believe me that instantiated Dynamic2Class object should conform my Dynamic2ClassProtocol.

Comment: In my case that swift part of my project that was interacting with Dynamic2.framework was not so huge so I just rewrote it using ObjC. 
But it's just interesting to find out how it can be solved.

Comment: In my case I used `Bundle` to load the framework, and Everything is Swift only. The protocol I cast the `principalClass` though needs to be `@objc`. I also used a Small Bridging Framework before that was Objective-C, but now it works in Swift as well.

Comment: One thing I am eager to know though is if dynamic loading will work at all with Swift under Linux. I guess I'll ask in the Swift forums.